# auto Tagging library or Script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Hi I am building my own news website using ASP.Net and I was wondring if there was an auto tagging library / script that I could use.

In the sense that When I create a new news article I specify the words I would like to tag and the library or script will search the text and insert an anchor element in that place.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried writing your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that does sounds like it does most of what you need:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

After including the script, add the highlight class to your css:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

Write some javascript to select the items you want to highlight, like:

```
$('li').highlight('bla');

// all occurences of 'bla' in a li element.
```

Comment: np. you may have to do some additional coding but should get you most of the way there.